# Web client front end download manager

Tags: server, downloads, webserver, download-manager

I currently run a headless server (Ubuntu server 12.10) with various applications running on the box accessed via web interfaces (transmission, plex etc). The box sits at a site with a quick and serves the purpose of being a central file repository, torrent box.

I was wondering if there was any application I could install on it which I could access via a web interface, password protected, which allowed me to punch in a file URL and it could download that file to a predetermined folder? Something similar to the transmission client for ubuntu server but for files off the web?

Answer (score 4):

You might have success using Aria2. Aria2 is a commandline only tool BUT there is a Web GUI as well that integrates with it so that might accomplish what you want. Aria2 comes in the USC, via PPA or as a DEB file though Aria2 doesn't host official deb packages but their PPA is official.

App - http://aria2.sourceforge.net/

WebGUI - https://github.com/ziahamza/webui-aria2

Answer (score 0):

[Libretto](http://libretto.sourceforge.net/) looks like what you're looking for. It doesn't have a .deb package, however.